# Python: How to calculate png crc value

Tags: python, image, image-processing, crc, crc32

```
crc_table = None

def make_crc_table():
  global crc_table
  crc_table = [0] * 256
  for n in xrange(256):
    c = n
    for k in xrange(8):
        if c & 1:
            c = 0xedb88320L ^ (c >> 1)
        else:
            c = c >> 1
    crc_table[n] = c

make_crc_table()

"""
/* Update a running CRC with the bytes buf[0..len-1]--the CRC
should be initialized to all 1's, and the transmitted value
is the 1's complement of the final running CRC (see the
crc() routine below)). */
"""
def update_crc(crc, buf):
  c = crc
  for byte in buf:
    c = crc_table[int((c ^ ord(byte)) & 0xff)] ^ (c >> 8)
  return c

# /* Return the CRC of the bytes buf[0..len-1]. */
def crc(buf):
  return update_crc(0xffffffffL, buf) ^ 0xffffffffL
```

I used this code to calculate png crc value
My IHDR chunk data is `000008A0 000002FA 08020000 00` and the result of that code was `0xa1565b1L`
However real crc was `0x84E42B87`. I checked this value with well known png checker tool and correct crc was `0x84E42B87`.
I can't understand how this value is calculated and correct value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CRC is calculated over the chunk type and the data, not just the data. So those bytes would be preceded by the four bytes `IHDR`. Then you get the correct CRC.

As an aside, I have no idea how you got `0xa1565b1L` from `000008A0 000002FA 08020000 00`. I get `0xa500050a` as the CRC of those bytes. There must be something else that you're doing wrong as well. You would need to provide a complete example for us to be able to tell.